# Firebase Dynamic Link doesn't redirect to the app when open through Safari

Tags: ios, firebase, mobile-safari, firebase-dynamic-links

I have added `Firebase Dynamic Link` in my app, when I open in `iPhone` link through `Google Chrome`, it redirects me to the app, but when I'm trying to open app through `Safari` (I'm opening links through the Notes, not directly from the Safari), it doesn't open the app.

I'm testing on real device, not in simulator.

I have followed official [Firebase Dynamic Links Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive).

What can be wrong and how is possible to fix that?

Comment: is safari your default browser.?

Comment: Yes, Safari is my default browser!

Comment: have you set url scheme? and are you receiving callback in you appDelegate class method name "openURL"?.

Comment: I have set URL Scheme, I don’t receive anything in the callback because app hasn’t been invoked when open through Safari

Comment: okay, do you have idea of Chrome uses URI schemes, Safari defaults to Universal links?

Comment: I have heart of that

Comment: I have enabled Associated domains in Capabilties tab in Xcode and also have added in Info Tab new URL Scheme

Comment: have you gone through to this document. https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive.

Comment: follow above mention link steps that will work. otherwise you should past specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that in `Xcode` in `Capabilities` Tab in Associated Domains, in Domains field, I wrote wrong domain, instead of appplinks:`app_id.app.goo.gl` I wrote:  `appplinks:app_id.goo.gl`, so i missed `.app`, after `app_id`, after changing it, it starts work correctly!

Comment: according to firebase official doc, we should set the value in associated domains like this applinks:your_subdomain.page.link 
Could you please let me know what app_id and app as an example

Answer (score 1):

add applinks:appName.page.link  to associated domain in xcode

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains
 you can't open your app through safari , you can open it only by clicking on the link or scanning it(QR) using iPhone camera

Comment: I do have this added and I am not typing URL in safari but rather adding it to the notes and clicking on the link from there, and still it only opens it in safari and not in the app. It does work fine in the simulator, though, so I am lost. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing we discovered while trying to implement Firebase Dynamic Linking in our app was that the Apple App Association File had to be in the .well_known directory on the web server. **Apple's app association documentation states the association file can be in either the root or .well_known**:

```
Place this file either in your site’s .well-known directory, or directly in its root directory.
```

[Setting Up an App's Association File](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/setting_up_an_app_s_associated_domains)

However, in looking at the web server logs when performing a fresh install of the app on a device, we saw calls being made to the .well_known directory. Once we copied the association file to the .well_known directory, Firebase Dynamic Linking worked as expected.