# Firebase Dynamic link not working correctly on device running iOS13.3, but working correctly on simulator (iOS13.2) and an iPhone running iOS12

Tags: firebase, ios13, swift5, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a dynamic link that opens when clicked, but is behaving differently on various devices and the simulator.

The link is behaving correctly on the simulator (running iOS13.2), and a device (iPhone7 running iOS12). The link is correctly redirecting the user back to the app, but on my iPhone X (iOS13.3.1) the link is redirecting me the App Store listing.

We have updated Pods 'Firebase' and 'FirebaseDynamicLinks' to their most current versions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am not sure there's enough information in the question to even hazard a guess. Did you try searching SO for some further information? Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724415/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app-ios) and this [github](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/857) and also this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030395/firebase-dynamic-link-doesnt-redirect-to-the-app-when-open-through-safari) which seems relevant.

Comment: I have a same problem. Have you find any solution for this?